# PHP: COM object not created in schedule task (instead hangs)

Tags: php, com

I have a PHP script that runs a process to generate letters on a Windows server.  The file is current set up as a Scheduled Task.

In the script, the COM object is instantiated to work with the appropriate files. When it is run as a Scheduled Task, the line to instantiate the COM object does nothing and hangs the script (rather than returning any result). The script will never terminate.

```
$this->word = new COM("word.application");
```

I believe that there is no issue with the script itself, as I can run the batch file directly (with no issue). This problem only seems to come up when we try to automate it.

I think there is some permissions issue going on, but I'm not entirely sure.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:

More information about the system:

Windows 2008 Server Standard without HyperV
Microsoft Office Word 2007
PHP 5.3.10
Attempting to Automate

Comment: What user is the scheduled task running as?

Comment: The user was running as a domain administrator and had explicit permissions for accessing the Word application

Comment: ... but what about the scheduled task?  The scheduled tasks can run as other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.  It was a profile issue.

In:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile
```

check to see if the `Desktop` folder exists.

If it doesn't, create it.

It has this issue because it is expecting the folder, but hangs when it can't find it.