# Windows Server 2008 Scheduled Task - MS Word Hangs

Tags: operating-system, ms-word, windows-server-2008, ms-office, scheduled-tasks

We have recently "upgraded" a server from 2003 to Windows 2008.  We have a scheduled task which kicks off a VB6 exe.  This exe grabs a file from an FTP server, starts Word, properly formats the file, saves it as a PDF and emails it.  The exe grabs the file from the FTP server fine but when it starts Word for the formatting step, WINWORD.exe appears in Task Manager and never does anything.  However, if I start it manually and not as a scheduled task, it runs OK.  I have the scheduled task set to the "Run with Highest Privileges" setting and I've tried changing the user under which it runs to several different privileged users with no success.  If I run it with the "run only if user is logged in" option checked and I'm logged in as that user, it runs but if I check the "run even if user is not logged in" option, it doesn't run even if I am logged in as that user.

The [desktop folder exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317519/php-com-object-not-created-in-schedule-task-instead-hangs) for all the users which are used to run the scheduled task so I don't think this is the problem.  I tried setting the ["Start In" optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler) but that didn't work either.  Also, the server is 32 bit so [using 32 bit emulation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification/thread/29446adf-8304-4b9f-bbc4-95daf2941d53) isn't going to work either.  Seriously, we're completely at a loss here.  Any help anyone can give would be appreciated.